# Get address from service reference C#

Tags: c#, ip-address, code-behind, service-reference

I have a project that has a service reference to a web service.  Is there a way from the codebehind to get the  actual http address of the service reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could retrieve it from the client proxy that was generated for you:

```
using (var client = new ServiceReference1.MyServiceClient("*"))
{
    string address = client.Endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString();
}
```

or if you are having multiple endpoints in your config file:

```
using (var client = new ServiceReference1.MyServiceClient("MyService"))
{
    var address = client.Endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Superb.  Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the generated proxy will have a `Url` property.